# Android facebook request not shown as notification

Tags: android, facebook-requests

I have integrated FacebookSDK to my Android application and I would like to perform an invite action on my Android app.

I have tried following the following two links to have my application successfully login via facebook and send application requests to my friends with a preview available before sending out:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/login-with-facebook/
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/send-requests/

However, for other platforms like facebook mobile and desktop website, notification is not shown. Notification is shown only on Facebook for Android.

By viewing app requests on Desktop website, the message passed by the following code cannot be seen:

```
params.putString("message", "Let us watch \""+node.getString("movieName")+"\" together");
```

Only showing "someone" invited you to try "myApp".

Should any code added in addition to the code on documentation to enable the message and notification shown on all platforms.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have same problem did you find solution for this?

Comment: i have the same problem. notification was showing Game->request. There must be some settings for these to appear in notifications.